# Add button next to material table column headers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, material-table

I would like to override the material table headers so that they include a button next to them while also preserving the out of the box features such as sorting button and click and drag to move columns. At the moment when you override headers you must override the entire header component, how can I override each column header individually so that I can add a button next to each header while preserving the material table header features?

Thanks

Comment: did you find a solution for this?

Comment: what I had to do was go to the material table github and copy over the code for their mtable-header component and add my button in it. Then I overrided the header component in the MTable through the props.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function

```
const createHeaderCell = (title, buttonTitle) => {
   return (<TableCell>
     <div style={{display: "flex", flexDirection: "row">
     {title}
     <Button style={{marginRight: 5}} onClick={() => console.log("clicked")}> 
     {buttonTitle}
     </Button>
     </div>
   </TableCell>)
 }
```

And then use it in your TableHeader like:

```
<TableHeader>
    <TableRow>
        {createHeaderCell("first", "1st button")}
        {createHeaderCell("second", "2nd button")}
    </TableRow>
</TableHeader>
```

Comment: Yes I know, but Is there a way to do this without losing the features that material table  has like sorting button and click and drag to move column headers?